# c# - memory usage during filestream.seek and marshal.copy

Tags: c#, memory, bitmap, marshalling, filestream

I have a running code, which gets any filetypes and show that file in a picturebox full of black and white pixels representing opened file bits

```
////////////////         
int bmpWidth = 128000;
int startIndex = 0;      
Int64 tempz = Convert.ToInt64(bmpWidth);
long tmp2 = fs.Length / tempz + 1;
int bmpHeight = Convert.ToInt32(tmp2);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bmpWidth, bmpHeight, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
////////////////
long all = 0;
byte[] array = new byte[bmpWidth];
int read = 0;

fs.Seek(startIndex, SeekOrigin.Begin);
all += startIndex;

BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
Int64 ptrFirstPixel = bmpData.Scan0.ToInt64();
int y = 0;
while ((read = fs.Read(array, 0, array.Length)) > 0)
{ 
    if (read < array.Length)
    {
        byte[] arrayNew = new byte[read];
        Array.Copy(array, arrayNew, read);
        array = arrayNew;
    }
    Marshal.Copy(array, 0, new IntPtr(ptrFirstPixel + y * bmpData.Stride), array.Length/8);
    y++;
    all += read;
}
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);       
imageBox.Image = bmp;
```

- I have a 4GB ram, how its possible that I'm opening a 4.5GB file?
- And also, when I try opening 2 or 4 GB file, only 200MB of memory is used, where are the rest of the data coming from?
- During marshal.copy and filestream.seek the system use memory for byte by byte for hole filestream and bitmap or its coming from hard disk?

I have a logical and semantic misunderstanding in my mind, any help!?

Comment: Swap space.  When you run out of memory it is stored on you disk in swap space.

Comment: So, there should be a point where my memory is going to be full and after that the swaping will be considered. But as I said when I open a 500MB file, only 200Mb is used, and when I open a 2GB file again memory usage is the same...

Comment: You are assuming that swapping occurs only when memory is full.  Swapping occurs before memory is full.

Comment: this program is supposed to run on a server with a 32GB or more RAM, as you said, for opening a 20GB file, again system would use disk swap instead of memory?!

Comment: Yes.  Windows is a multi-user operating system so the memory must support all the processes.  So as the processes swap (active/inactive) so does the memory they use.